# zcat | head : write error from large gz file

Tags: linux, stdout, head

I was trying zcat to get only the first 1M lines of a compressed .gzip file into a new one.

However, I get the following error:

```
$ zcat path/to/R2.fq.gz | head -100 >R2.fqtest
head: write error: Input/output error
```

I was relieved when I found this thread and tried:

```
$ gunzip -c path/to/R2.fq.gz | head -n100 >R2_test.fq
```

But I get the same error again!

```
head: write error: Input/output error
```

Anyone know what might be going on and how to fix it?

thanks! Carmen

Edit >

As requested, I typed the following after getting the error

```
tail /var/log/syslog
```

and got

```
tail: cannot open `/var/log/syslog' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The command itself is correct. Right after the getting the error, execute `tail /var/log/syslog` and edit the result into your question.

Comment: Done! :) I got `tail: cannot open '/var/log/syslog' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: Well, that didn't turn out to be particularly helpful... Which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like a problem with zcat/gunzip. Can you create the file and write into it?

Try this:

```
hexdump /dev/urandom | head -n 100 > R2_test.fq
```

Comment: `hexdump /dev/urandom | head -n 100 >R2_test.fq`


    I get this:
`head: write error: Input/output error`

Comment: then you probably can't write in the file R2_test.fq . Try it from a directory where you have write access.

Comment: pqnet, I do have access to the folder where I am trying to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

In order, please try and post results of:

```
head -n 10 /proc/cpuinfo
echo test | gzip -3 | zcat
echo test > R2.fqtest
```

The goal here is to first test for proper operation of `head`, then proper operation of `zcat`, then the ability to successfully write to `R2.fqtest`.

Since you state that everything works as expected until the attempt to write to R2.fqtest, which does not throw an error but also doesn't show the data you wrote, there's something hinky with that file or underlying filesystem.  Does another process write, lock, or rotate that file? What does the fstab line for the filesystem in question look like?  Can you unmount and fsck the filesystem in question?  Do you see errors in the logs from the physical drive underlying that filesystem?

Comment: Thanks, Jim:

The output of `head -n 10 /proc/cpuinfo` is:

`processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 45
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2665 0 @ 2.40GHz
stepping : 7
cpu MHz  : 1200.000
cache size : 20480 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 16`
;
`echo test | gzip -3 | zcat`   returns `test` as expected;

and

`echo test > R2.fqtest` does not return an error, but if I open R2.fqtest there is nothing there...

Comment: (Note - the new edit is me as well; didn't realize I wasn't logged in until I'd posted!)

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out this is a problem of not having enough disk space!

Thanks, eveyone!

Carmen